# Cannot Access updated state in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to update my state in a called function but I'm always getting the initial value of `filteredDestinations` or `parskWithDestinations` which is an empty array inside `filterDestinations`.

I don't know it cannot access the updated values

Do you have any ideas where it's from?

```
const Destinations = () => {
  const [destinationsFilters, setDestinationsFilters] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [filteredDestinations, setFilteredDestinations]: any = useState([])
  const [parskWithDestinations, setParskWithDestinations] = useState([])

  const constructActivityItemsList = (destinations: any) => {
    const activityItemsList = []
    destinations.forEach(destination => {
      activityItemsList.push({
        title: destination?.destinationName,
        items: destination?.parks?.map(park => {
          return {
            title: destination?.destinationName,
            subtitle: park?.name,
            location: park?.country,
            image: {
              url: park?.cardImage?.url,
              alt: park?.cardImage?.alt,
            },
            logo: park?.logo,
            link: `http://localhost:3000/destinations/${park?.slug}/`,
          }
        }),
      })
    })
    return activityItemsList
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    DestinationService.getParksFromDestination()
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          setFilteredDestinations(constructActivityItemsList(response.data))
          setParskWithDestinations(response.data)
          setDestinationsFilters(constructFilters(response.data))
          console.log(constructFilters(response.data))
          setIsLoading(false)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        setError(err)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  const filterDestinations = (searchDestination: string) => {
    if (searchDestination === 'All') {
      setFilteredDestinations(filteredDestinations)
    } else {
      console.log(filteredDestinations)
      console.log(parskWithDestinations)
      const foundDestinations = filteredDestinations.filter(destination => {
        return destination.title === searchDestination
      })
      setFilteredDestinations(foundDestinations)
    }
  }

  const constructFilters = (destinations: any) => {
    const filters = [
      {
        title: 'All',
        onClick: () => filterDestinations('All'),
      },  
    ]
    destinations.forEach(destination => {
      filters.push({
        title: destination.destinationName,
        onClick: () => filterDestinations(destination.name),
      })
    })
    return filters
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ParkTimeRow fullWidth>
        <ActivityHeroComponent
          title={'Destinations'}
          images={{
            desktopImgUrl:
              'https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i2401adc8c9decc07/version/1454162276/image.jpg',
            mobileImgUrl:
              'https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i2401adc8c9decc07/version/1454162276/image.jpg',
            imageAlt: 'destinations alt',
          }}
          displayStatus={false}
        ></ActivityHeroComponent>
      </ParkTimeRow>
      {!isLoading && (
        <>
          <ParkTimeRow>
            <FilterModule
              title="Quick Access"
              items={destinationsFilters.sort((item, prevItem) =>
                SortArray(item, prevItem, 'title')
              )}
            />
          </ParkTimeRow>
          {filteredDestinations.length > 0 &&
            filteredDestinations.map((destination, index) => {
              if (destination?.items) {
                return (
                  <ParkTimeRow key={`destination-list-${index}`}>
                    <ListingActivity
                      title={destination?.title}
                      items={destination?.items}
                    />
                  </ParkTimeRow>
                )
              }
            })}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default Destinations
```

Comment: Setting state is async. You need to look into the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Comment: `setFilteredDestinations(filteredDestinations)` -- doesn't make sense. Did you mean `setFilteredDestinations(searchDestination)`?

Comment: yes it was a test but even when I  console.log(filteredDestinations) at the beginning of the function i get an empty array @C.Helling

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, setState is not immediate, setState calls can get batched together in one update. Instead, look into `React.useCallabck` with dependent states in the dependency array of the callback.

Comment: It doesnt change when i'm using useCallback within my states :/